# Binding strings to list in controller

Tags: c#, string, list, asp.net-mvc-4, binding

I have a form in View where are multiple  fields. I send them to controller and I want to bind them to List. How can I achieve this?

For now i have this code

View

```
using (Html.BeginForm("GetVendorInvoice", "Sale", FormMethod.Get))
{
    foreach (var invoice in Model.VendorInvoices)
    { 
        @Html.Hidden("invoiceId", invoice.InvoiceId)
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Wszystkie na raz"/>
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetVendorInvoice(List<string> invoiceIdList) {
...}
```

I read some article that said it shoud work but actually it does not.
Any sugestions?

Comment: invoiceId list you want?

Comment: Yes. In Model they are declared as string type

Comment: The controller code that you put there is the Post or the get? Also what do you want to do in the view with that list? What's not working?

Comment: Its get. In the view i just want to send list of strings to the controller. This list has variable amount of items.  Now, when i send this form to controller the invoiceIdList is null. I checked in view that all hidden fields are correctly populated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have property name **InvoiceId** while in action you paremeter is **invoiceIdList** which is wrong and list will be null in the action, do like this in action:

```
public ActionResult GetVendorInvoice(List<string> InvoiceId) {
    ...}
```

or you can do like this:

```
foreach (var invoice in Model.VendorInvoices)
    { 
        @Html.Hidden("InvoiceId", invoice.InvoiceId)
    }
```

action:

```
public ActionResult GetVendorInvoice(List<string> invoiceId) {
...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actions:

```
public virtual ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(new HomepageModel()
    {
            Strings = new[] {"one", "two", "three"}
    });
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(List<string> strings)
{
    throw new Exception(String.Join(", ", strings));
}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Strings.Length; ++i)
     {
         @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Strings[i])
     }

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

You should use the `HiddenFor` helper method instead of Hidden, as this is strongly typed and will ensure your view matches the model. Using the indexer will generate the correct names for the hidden fields.

Answer (score 0):

I heve found the answer. First of all there was an error. Filed name in view was different from parameter name in controller. When i fixed this i have got a string of hidden fields values separated with commas. Now i have to split this string and everithing is fine now. 
Thanks for Your effort.

Comment: yes instead of this List<string> invoiceIdList you need to do List<string> invoiceId